# How to safely and securely interact with a Database from a WPF App

Tags: c#, database, wpf, entity-framework, security

As I developped a **WPF .NET Core** Application that interacts with an online **MySQL Database** using `EntityFramework`, I noticed I had absolutely no way of protecting my Database from being read or modified using the easily accessible connection string if my app was deployed and someone code reversed it.

I searched a bit and found these few possible solutions:

- Storing the connection string in an encrypted `app.config` using `aspnet_regiis` *(but .NET Core seems to be more oriented on `.json` configuration files, and therefore cannot be encrypted using `aspnet_regiis`)*
- Obfuscating the source code using an c# obfuscator like `ConfuserEx` *(if I understood correctly it's just making the connection string harder to read, but it remains possible to get it and mess with the DB right?)*
- Building and interacting with API instead that would do the changes to the DB *(but even then how to make sure the API requests are truly coming from my WPF app and not from a malicious user?)*

If you know any more precisions about these solutions or perhaps have another way of making it secure and safe to connect to an online Database, detailed steps/links are very welcome!

Comment: One option is to store the configuration key in an environment variable and read out the value in code.

Comment: If you have a super user or internal authoriser you can let users register username and password. Store these in your database. A person looks at these and decides they're a trusted user and authorises these. Each user then has their own unique username and password. To reduce the risk of network sniffing, a log on can be used to generate a token. A long-ish randomised string. This is valid for a day and cached on the web server. Each request passes a token unique to the user for that day.

Comment: Unless of course the users are on the same domain as the server. In which case you can just use their windows log on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and tests, I found that the proper way to prevent a malicious user from reading and messing up with the connected database *(even if he gets access to the connection string)* is by **Limiting my app to only execute Stored Procedures** that will give the minimum data required. And for stored procedures that will read or change a user's sensitive data, also by having in their required parameters the user's secret token, which would be a random string generated in SQL the same time the user registers.

The only issue remaining is if the hacker spams requests to try to bruteforce (even if it's almost impossible to bruteforce a very long and safe token), it might still makes the MySQL server overload or even crash. To prevent that from happening the only solution seems to use an API.

Answer (score 0):

> Building and interacting with API instead that would do the changes to the DB

This would be the recommended approach.

> (but even then how to make sure the API requests are truly coming from my WPF app and not from a malicious user?)

You can't really.

When you embed some kind of access key or a public URL in a client application that you expose publicly, you basically accept the fact that it may be exposed. You should assume that a malicious user can extract the key/URL from the client app regardless of any obfuscation.

The service may reject requests from IP addresses that it considers to be misusing the API but it will still need to handle those requests.

Managing a public API is not trivial. You may want to consider hosting your app in a managed cloud.